# Gmail api: How do I get the recipient's email using the ID?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to get the recipient's email using the ID that I have retrieved. Below is the code.

```
messages = service.users().threads().list(userId='me', q='to:').execute().get('threads', [])
    for message in messages:
        #print(message)
        # print(dir(message))
        # print(message.get())
        if search in message['snippet']:
            #print(message['id'])
            message_id = message['id']
            # print(message_id)
            full_message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id, format="raw").execute()
            #print(full_message)
            msg_headers = full_message['payload']['headers']
            #print(msg_headers)
            msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(full_message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
            mime_msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg_str)

            #print(mime_msg)

            x = re.findall('id=(\w+)\'', str(mime_msg))
            print(x)
            if len(x)> 0:
                return x[0]
                if msg_headers[x]['name'] == "To":
                    return msg_headers[x[0]]['value']
            else:
                return None
```

I get the error below. How do I resolve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\test2.py", line 102, in <module>
    test = get_email_with("Test string")
  File "C:\test\test2.py", line 55, in get_email_with
    msg_headers = full_message['payload']['headers']
KeyError: 'payload'
```

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Also, please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC I have tried debugging.

Comment: I mean the Error said, full_message doesnt have any element with the key 'payload', try debug this object to look if its empty, or its in another structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

When the format is set to `RAW`, the field `payload` is not populated in the response.

From the API [official docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/Format):

> **RAW**: Returns the full email message data with body content in the raw field as a base64url encoded string; **the payload field is not used**.

#### Solution:

Use either `FULL` or `METADATA` as format when calling `messages().get`, instead of `RAW` (format is an option parameter, and if it is not specified, `FULL` is used as default).

So you should change this:

```
full_message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id, format="raw").execute()
```

To this:

```
full_message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id).execute()
```

Or, alternatively, use `format="raw"` anyway and decode the base-64 encoded string `full_message["raw"]`. **Edit**: In this case, though, you'd have to remove this line: `msg_headers = full_message['payload']['headers']`.

#### Edit:

So, if you want to retrieve the recipient, you can do the following:

```
full_message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id).execute()
msg_headers = full_message['payload']['headers']
for header in msg_headers:
    if header["name"] == "To":
        return header["value"]
```

#### Reference:

- [API reference > Format](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/Format)

Comment: @lamblichus thank you! when I do not use "raw", I have an error for my base-64 decoding.

Comment: @yeroduk Since you would not be using `raw`, you don't need to decode. You'd just need to look for the `To` header in `msg_headers`. I have edited my answer with a code snippet to do that, I hope this is helpful to you. And if you want to use `raw` anyway, you would have to remove this line: `msg_headers = full_message['payload']['headers']`.

Answer (score 1):

The response from Gmail can be a little confusing.   You are on the right track with

```
 msg_headers = full_message['payload']['headers']
```

One of the headers is called has a name of "Delivered-To" the value will be the email address that the mail was sent to.  So basiclly you need to search your msg_headers and find the one called "Delivered-To"

Unfortunately i am not a python dev i cant help you with the code.  [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) may give you some ideas on how to get the response out of the object.

## response

```
 "payload": {
    "partId": "",
    "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Delivered-To",
        "value": "xxxx@gmail.com"
      },
```